# Ошибка при работе с Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Что нужно:

1. `JS` отправляет информацию в переменной `login` на php
2. `PHP` проверяет, зарегистрирован ли логин (из переменной `login`) и если нет - отправляет на js `true`, если да - `false`
3. `JS` принимает информацию и делает проверку: если передано значение `true` - выполняет один код, если `false` - другой.

Что происходит:
Ничего. Либо `php` не отправляет ответ, либо `js` не принимает.

Код:

JS:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open("POST", "check.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(login);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (){
  if(xhr.readyState == 4){
    if(xhr.responseText == "true"){
      var div = document.querySelector("#login");
      div.className = "true";
      div.innerHTML = "✓Логин не занят";
      alogin = null;
      alogin = true;
    }else if(xhr.responseText == "false"){
      var div = document.querySelector("#login");
      div.className = "false";
      div.innerHTML = "Логин занят!";
      alogin = null;
      alogin = false;
    }
  }
}
```

check.php:

```
<?php
include("db.php");
if(isset($_POST["login"]){
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    if($login == ''){
        unset($login);
    }
    $login = stripslashes($login);
    $login = htmlspecialchars($login);
    $login = trim($login);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE login='$login'", $db);
    $myray = mysql_fecth_array($result);
    if(!empty($myray['id'])){
        echo 'false';
    }else{
        echo 'true';
    }
}
?>
```

db.php:

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("194.67.202.210", "testsite", "не скажу");
mysql_select_db("LHVideo", $db);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<input id='login' onchange='check();'>
<div id='hint'></div>
```

JS

```
function check() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open("POST", "ttt9.php", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(login);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (){
        if(xhr.readyState == 4){
            var div = document.getElementById("hint");
            if(xhr.responseText == "true"){
                div.className = "true";
                div.innerHTML = "?Логин не занят";
                alogin = null;
                alogin = true;
            }else if(xhr.responseText == "false"){
                div.className = "false";
                div.innerHTML = "Логин занят!";
                alogin = null;
                alogin = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```